# Refreshing only part of QgsMapCanvas?

Tags: pyqgis, c++, qgsmapcanvas

When using the refresh() function, is it possible to only refresh part of the map canvas, instead of refreshing all of it?

I am using C++ but can use any code snippet even if it is in Python.

Comment: QgsMapCanvas inherit from qgraphicsview, and I think that isn't possible